# Is there a way to covert all columns with int to float

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all the columns of dataframe with dtype as int to float. How can I achieve this? I dont know the name of the columns which are int so might need to use `if == int` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
columns = df.select_dtypes(include='int').columns

df[columns] = df[columns].astype(float)
```